# change radio selection value to image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, replace

I have this webapp which is fed by customers with the reviews of the products
they select a radio option with the stars they give to the products which are 1 to 5, and I want that the value to be replaced for a selected image for each value.

the output of the radio its just a text on a div I called "reviews-adh"

it goes like this

```
<div clas="reviews-adh">
<table>
<tr>
<td>3
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

and I have this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ztwhw601/3/) that it replaces the value of 5 but I need to make it to replace the values from 1 to 5 for any image I input the URL of the image like in the jsfiddle example.

Comment: So you want to have 5 stars instead of 5 radio buttons?

Comment: yes i want to have the customer to select from 1 to 5 stars and since its a redio button will display a 1 to 5 value and in that case i want to have 5 images that each one will replace each value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding you want something like this? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ztwhw601/4/)

```
$('div.reviews-adh').each(function() {
    var starNumber = Number($(this).text())+1,
        images = '';
    for (i = 1; i < starNumber; i++) { 
       images += '<img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/58c736/ffffff.png&text='+i+'">';
    }

    $(this).html(images);
});
```

Comment: this works awesome but its not what im looking for since i need it to replace the values from 1 to 5 with its own image lets say the value 1 will be replaced with the image1 and the value 2 will be replaced with the image2 and so on.

Comment: My example replaces the value `ex. 3` with `image-3`, do you want to display from 1 to 3 (3 images) instead? I recommend you use css to make this star rating.

Comment: yes i want to have in this case 5 images and replace each value with his image